# How to set Infragistics UltraGrid cell programatically

Tags: c#, infragistics, ultrawingrid

I'm trying to do the following a) a user selects a cell in an UltraGrid b)the row/column is stored from the ClickCell event handler c) the grid has its datasource changed d) the saved row/column is used to re-select the same cell, which now has different data under it.

By changing the datasource InitalizeLayout is fired and InitializeRow fired for each row in the grid.

The problem I have is reselecting the row/column on the grid.  I've tried various methods using the Activation/Activate methods/properties on the cell, which do not seem to work at all.  I've also tried just changing the color of the cell, but then I need to fire an event on a row which no longer has focus.

This seems like it should be straight forward. Any suggestions?

Thanks.